# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

I am having an error with my Python function. The code is shown below.

```
def vigenere():
    message1 = input('message: ')
    keyl = ['l', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'n']
    if len(message1) > len(keyl):
        keyl = [i * 5 for i in keyl]
    else:
        pass
    for med in message1:
              encrypting = chr(ord(med) + ord(keyl[med]))
              print(encrypting)
    encmessage = input('Is there a message you would like to decrypt?')
    for mes in encmessage:
        decrypting = chr(ord(med) - ord(keyl[med]))
        print(decrypting)
```

The python shell demonstrates an error when I attempt to call my function. The error is shown below.

> ================ RESTART: /Users/ggmac/Documents/ProjectM.py================
>   vigenere()
>   message: flee
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "", line 1, in 
>        vigenere()
>      File "/Users/gg-mac/Documents/ProjectM.py", line 75, in vigenere
>        encrypting = chr(ord(med) + ord(keyl[med]))
>    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Could you please help and inform me of my error?

Answer (score 2):

List index must be integer. The following should fix your problem.

```
def vigenere():
    message1 = input('message: ')
    keyl = ['l', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'n']
    if len(message1) > len(keyl):
        keyl = [i * 5 for i in keyl]
    else:
        pass
    for i,med in enumerate(message1):
              encrypting = chr(ord(med) + ord(keyl[i]))
              print(encrypting)
    encmessage = input('Is there a message you would like to decrypt?')
    for k, mes in enumerate(encmessage):
        decrypting = chr(ord(med) - ord(keyl[k]))
        print(decrypting)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed my problem.

Comment: Now worries. Please accept it as your answer if it's helpful.